# React, filter is not working after refreshing the component

Tags: reactjs, filter

EDIT: for some reason it works in production, however I can't proceed on dev mode.

I'm writing a Contacts Book app, which shows "main" contacts and "subcontacts". When I first load this contacts book, it just run as expected, contacts are loaded successfully within the Busqueda(means search) component, which is an autocomplete that loads all the contacts and when one is selected, the information in displayed in other components.
I have buttons to edit contact, subcontact and erase them too, however, when I do any of these actions, I send a "reload" action so the list is updated with the changes, and it throws `allResults.filter is not a function` as `allResults` seems to be an object.

```
function Agenda() {
  
  const MiContexto = useOutletContext();
  useEffect(()=>{MiContexto.CrearContactoModalDispatch(false); },[]);

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] =useState(null);
  const [selectedSubContact, setSelectedSubContact] =useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
     MiContexto.setSelectedContact(selectedValue);
     MiContexto.setAgenda_nombre_empresa(selectedValue?.nombre_empresa);
  },[selectedValue]);

  const [allResults, setAllResults] =useState([]);
  const [coincideArray, setCoincideArray] =useState(allResults?.filter(entry => entry?.empresa_id === selectedValue?.empresa_id));
  const [reloadBusqueda,setReloadBusqueda] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setCoincideArray(allResults?.filter(entry => entry?.empresa_id === selectedValue?.id_empresa));
  },[allResults!==null, selectedValue]);
  
  return (
    <div className={'outletBasicSetting'}>
      <Busqueda setSelectedValue={setSelectedValue} allResults={setAllResults} reload={reloadBusqueda}/>
      <Grid container>

        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <EntidadPrincipal selectedValue={selectedValue}/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid container item xs={12} md={6}>
          {coincideArray[0]?.id_empresa && coincideArray?.map((persona)=>{
            return(
              <Grid key={persona.id_contacto} item xs={12} md={6}>
                <SubEntidad persona={persona}/>
              </Grid>)
          })}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <CrearContacto opening={MiContexto.CrearContactomodal} setReloadBusqueda={setReloadBusqueda}/>
      
      {coincideArray[0]?.id_empresa
      ?
      <EditarQuien openQuien={MiContexto.quienModal} contacto={selectedValue} coincideArray={coincideArray} setReloadBusqueda={setReloadBusqueda} setSelectedSubContact={setSelectedSubContact}/>
      :
      <EditarContactoP opening={MiContexto.quienModal} setReloadBusqueda={setReloadBusqueda} contacto={selectedValue}/>}
      <EditarContactoP opening={MiContexto.EditarPModal} setReloadBusqueda={setReloadBusqueda} contacto={selectedValue}/>
      <EditarContactoS opening={MiContexto.EditarCModal} setReloadBusqueda={setReloadBusqueda} contacto={selectedSubContact}/>
      <CrearSubContacto opening={MiContexto.crearSubContactoModal} setReloadBusqueda={setReloadBusqueda} contacto={selectedValue}/>
      <BorrarQuien openBorrarQuien={MiContexto.borrarCualContactoAgendaModal} contacto={selectedValue} coincideArray={coincideArray} setReloadBusqueda={setReloadBusqueda} setSelectedSubContact={setSelectedSubContact}/>
      </div>
      
  );
}
```

Busqueda Component:

```
import { Autocomplete, Stack, TextField, Chip, Avatar, autocompleteClasses, styled, Popper } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ListboxComponent from './VariableSizeList';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
function Busqueda({setSelectedValue,allResults,reload}){
    const [jsonResults, setJsonResults] = useState([]);
    var token = "";
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState( null);
    const [storedSelected,setStoredSelected] = useState(null);
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e,v) =>{
      setSelected(v);
      setStoredSelected(v);
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
      token=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    },[]);

    useEffect(()=>{
      setSelectedValue(selected);
      allResults(jsonResults);
    },[allResults, jsonResults, selected, setSelectedValue]);

    const StyledPopper = styled(Popper)({
        [`& .${autocompleteClasses.listbox}`]: {
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          '& ul': {
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
          },
        },
      });
      
     useEffect(() => {
      console.time("Tiempo de carga de LeerAgenda");    
      fetch(process.env['REACT_APP_DEV_PROXY']+"https://server.com/file.php",{ 
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{'Token':token["token"]},
        body: "",
        })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json)=>{
        setJsonResults(json);      
        console.timeEnd("Tiempo de carga de LeerAgenda");
        setSelected(null);
      }) 
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error(JSON.stringify(err["msg"]));
        console.error("Se catcheo un error: "+err["msg"]);
      })
    },[reload])



    return  (
         <Autocomplete
            open={open}
            onInputChange={(_, value) => {
              if (value.length === 0) {
                if (open) setOpen(false);
              } else {
                if (!open) setOpen(true);
              }
            }}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
            value={selected}
            id="agenda"
            disableListWrap
            ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
            getOptionLabel={jsonResults => jsonResults?.nombre_contacto ?
              jsonResults?.nombre_empresa +": "+jsonResults?.nombre_contacto
              : jsonResults?.nombre_empresa
          } //lo que aparece en la caja al seleccionar 
            options={jsonResults}
            PopperComponent={StyledPopper}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Busca aquí el contacto"/>}
            renderOption={(props, jsonResults) => [props, 
                 <>
                 <Chip label={jsonResults.nombre_empresa} color="primary" size="small" avatar={<Avatar>{jsonResults.nombre_empresa.charAt(0)}</Avatar>}/>
                 &nbsp;{jsonResults?.nombre_contacto}</>
            ]} // el texto de cada opcion desplegada
            onChange={handleChange}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option,value) =>  option.id_contacto === value.id_contacto}
            noOptionsText={"Tu texto no coincide con ningún resultado"}
        />
    </Stack>) 
  }
  export default Busqueda;
```

Comment: Please post the `Busqueda` component, maybe the component doesn't pass an array to the `setAllResults` callback.

Comment: @HedeH thank you, I added the busqueda component in order to be checked.

Comment: When you call `setJsonResults(json);` in the `Busqueda` component, what is the value of `json`? If it's an object the crash makes sense cause you can't do `object.filter` - it has to be an array to use the `filter` function.